# C# type String[] API

Tags: c#, sql, api, sqldatatypes

I am using a small GUI to run some RestAPIs and update the data in my own SQL DB. I created a API model and a helper class to load the API and save them into the SQL DB. 99% works perfectly, but there is one column which i am unable to save to the DB. The API calls a column which is a text or array type. it looks like this when I am running the API in the browser:
`"description": [ "Here is written some text", "And here the text goes on. its separated because of the length!"]`

In my API model I call this column with `public string[] description { get; set; }`. This works fine but the problem is to save it then to the SQL DB. There I created a table with the column description type text.

the error message I am getting is: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The given value of type String[] from the data source cannot be converted to type text of the specified target column.'`

Has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You may need to re-join that string array to a simple string first

Comment: save it as json and then you can retrieve it as json, libraries are for processing json are enoug around

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to store an array in a single column. Maybe you can try a seperate table with the `Id` as a foreign key and a description. That way you can store multiple descriptions for 1.